# In iOS PDFPage(image:image) makes the PDF file size larger. How to solve this issue?

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

File sizes of the captured 5 images are around 5MB each. It should be on average 25MB but the PDF file size is around 120MB. What is the issue?

```
    let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
    var pageCount = 0
    var originalSize = 0

    // where images are picked from ImagePicker
    for image in images {
        let imgData = NSData(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!)
        let imageSize: Int = imgData.count
        originalSize = originalSize + imageSize

         if let jpgData = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75), let jpg = UIImage(data: jpgData) {
            if let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: jpg) {
                pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage, at: pageCount)
                pageCount += 1
            }
        }
    }
    print("ORIGINAL IMAGE SIZE: %fMB", Double(originalSize) / 1000000)

    let data = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()
    let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let docURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("Assignment-Docs.pdf")
    print("PDF SIZE:" + String(docURL.fileSize / 1000000) + "MB")
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you are actually comparing apples and oranges here. First you are using jpeg-Compression here: `NSData(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!)` and then you're using png data here: `if let pngData = image.pngData()`.

Those are two very different things.

Here is your adopted code I used inside a playground:

```
let pdfDocument = PDFDocument()
var pageCount = 0
var originalSize = 0

let images: [UIImage] = [UIImage(named: "icke,jpg", in: .main, with: nil),
                          UIImage(named: "cat.jpg", in: .main, with: nil)].compactMap { $0 }
for image in images {
    let imgData = NSData(data: image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)!)
    let imageSize: Int = imgData.count
    originalSize = originalSize + imageSize

        if let data = image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 0.75)/* image.pngData()*/, let image = UIImage(data: data) {
        if let pdfPage = PDFPage(image: image) {
            pdfDocument.insert(pdfPage, at: pageCount)
            pageCount += 1
        }
    }
}
print("ORIGINAL IMAGE SIZE: \(originalSize) Bytes")

let data = pdfDocument.dataRepresentation()
let documentDirectory = NSTemporaryDirectory()
let docURL = documentDirectory.appending("Assignment-Docs.pdf")
FileManager.default.createFile(atPath: docURL, contents: data, attributes: nil)
let fileData = try? Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: docURL))
print("PDF SIZE: \(fileData!.count) Bytes")
```

Comment: The first 3 lines in the for loop is just to find the size of the original file. Then Below I tried to change type png or jpeg(0.75) but no luck.

Comment: If I do what you did with to small images using `image.pngData()` I get the same result with about double the pdf site compared to the original size. If I change the conversion method to `image.jpegData(compressionQuality: 1)` in both cases I get almost the identical sizes.
JPEG vs. PNG: `ORIGINAL IMAGE SIZE: 57492 Bytes
PDF SIZE: 116956 Bytes`
JPEG@1 vs. JPEG @1: `ORIGINAL IMAGE SIZE: 57492 Bytes
PDF SIZE: 61567 Bytes`
JPEG@1 vs. JPEG @0.75 `ORIGINAL IMAGE SIZE: 57492 Bytes
PDF SIZE: 39212 Bytes`